# Alternative for this Cursor SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

How can I do this without the cursor:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @VAR_A BIGINT, @VAR_B TINYINT;

DECLARE _CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT A, B FROM MY_TABLE

OPEN _CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR 
INTO @VAR_A, @VAR_B
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 2 A, B, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A DESC) AS ROW_NUM 
    INTO #TMP FROM MY_TABLE_2 
    WHERE A = @VAR_A AND X = 0 ORDER BY A DESC
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TMP) = 1) BEGIN
        UPDATE MY_TABLE 
          SET Y = (SELECT B FROM #TMP WHERE ROW_NUM = 1) 
        WHERE A = @VAR_A
    END ELSE IF (@VAR_B = 7) BEGIN
        UPDATE MY_TABLE 
        SET Y = (SELECT B FROM #TMP WHERE ROW_NUM = 2), 
            Z = (SELECT C FROM #TMP WHERE ROW_NUM = 2) 
        WHERE A = @VAR_A
    END ELSE BEGIN
        UPDATE MY_TABLE 
        SET Y = (SELECT B FROM #TMP WHERE ROW_NUM = 2) 
        WHERE A = @VAR_A
    END

    DROP TABLE #TMP

    FETCH NEXT FROM _CURSOR   
    INTO @VAR_A, @VAR_B
END   
CLOSE _CURSOR;  
DEALLOCATE _CURSOR;
```

I have a PRODUCT table, this table has a status column, the last status of the product. I have another table, the PRODUCT_HISTORY, that have all information changed on product, including the older status. For each product, I need to get the last status and insert it on a new field on product table. Like this:

[image: sample]

Comment: Instead of expecting us to dissect this cursor to understand it's intentions, why not explain what it does and what your overall problem is that you are trying to answer with this cursor? Since it's self referencing, a self-join is likely in order... also tagging your respective RDMS (version) would be wise.

Comment: I have a PRODUCT table, this table has a status column, the last status of the product. I have another table, the PRODUCT_HISTORY, that have all information changed on product, including the older status. For each product, I need to get the last status and insert it on a new field on product table.

Comment: Then no, you do not need a cursor. however, sample data and expected output is needed here...

Comment: sample added ...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Your date column has the word *DATE* in it? That's a new one for me :) Seriously, how can someone determine how you chose **1** as the *Older Status* for Product A? I would guess that it would be 5. Help us, help you.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Product;

CREATE TABLE #Product (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Description] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Status] INT NOT NULL,
    OlderStatus INT NULL 
    );

INSERT #Product (Id, [Description], [Status]) VALUES 
    (1, 'Product A', 5),
    (2, 'Product B', 7),
    (3, 'Product C', 4),
    (4, 'Product D', 3),
    (5, 'Product E', 0);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductHistory', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ProductHistory;

CREATE TABLE #ProductHistory (
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    Status INT NOT NULL,
    ProductId INT NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #ProductHistory (Id, [Date], [Status], ProductId) VALUES 
    (1, '2017-01-01', 0, 1),
    (2, '2017-01-02', 1, 1),
    (3, '2017-01-03', 5, 1),
    (4, '2017-01-04', 0, 2),
    (5, '2017-01-05', 1, 2),
    (6, '2017-01-06', 5, 2),
    (7, '2017-01-07', 7, 2),
    (8, '2017-01-08', 0, 3),
    (9, '2017-01-09', 4, 3),
    (10, '2017-01-10', 0, 4),
    (11, '2017-01-11', 3, 4),
    (12, '2017-01-12', 0, 5);

--===================================================

-- the actual solution...
WITH 
    cte_PH AS (
        SELECT 
            ph.Id, ph.Date, ph.Status, ph.ProductId,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ph.ProductId ORDER BY ph.Date DESC)
        FROM
            #ProductHistory ph
        )
UPDATE p SET
    p.OlderStatus = ISNULL(ph.Status, 0)
FROM
    #Product p
    LEFT JOIN cte_PH ph
        ON p.id = ph.ProductId
        AND ph.RN = 2;

----------------------------------------

SELECT * FROM #Product p;
```

Results...

```
Id          Description          Status      OlderStatus
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
1           Product A            5           1
2           Product B            7           5
3           Product C            4           0
4           Product D            3           0
5           Product E            0           0
```